# How do I solve this laravel layout issue?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

**My error:** I am facing this issue quite long time and found one solution in stackoverflow  but it doesn't work. I need solution to work with laravel , php 7+  and mysql.

It is showing below error:
ErrorException
Trying to get property 'app_layout' of non-object

Error page consists following code and i tried all solutions in stack overflow but no us. I want to show my layout without any error here.

**Error in the script\app\Http\Controllers\MainBaseController.php:26**

```
code on the page is : error line highlighted in BOLD below

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

use Froiden\Envato\Traits\AppBoot;

 

class MainBaseController extends Controller

{

 

    public function __construct()

    {

        parent::__construct();

 

        // Settings

        $this->settings = Setting::first();

        $this->year = Common::year();

        $this->bootstrapModalRight = true;

        $this->bootstrapModalSize = 'md';

        **$this->siteLayout = $this->settings->app_layout; // top, sidebar**

        $this->forbiddenErrorView = 'errors.403';

        $this->showFooter = true;

        $this->rtl = $this->settings->rtl;

 

        // Status

        $this->statusArray = [

            'enabled'  =>   __('app.enabled'),

            'disabled'  =>    __('app.disabled')

        ];

 

        // Setting assets path

        $allPaths = Common::getFolderPath();

        foreach($allPaths as $allPathKey => $allPath)

        {

            $this->{$allPathKey} = $allPath;
```

I am placing error part of the code above , if you need any other parts i will provide

Comment: `$this->settings` is not an object. Try `Log::info($this->settings);` above the line to find out what it is. That will log it to a file in `storage/logs`

Comment: Which laravel version you are using ?

Comment: dd(Setting::first()) to check what it returns.

Comment: yea, the `$this->settings` is not an object, most likely it is `null`. What do you expect it to be? where do you think it is coming from?